# Custom environment with minipage and align*

Tags: xetex, environments

I would like to have an environment that puts two equations side by side. The following works but Is there a way to make this a dedicated `newenvironment`?

```
  \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{equation}
        y_1(x)=x^2
      \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{equation}
        y_2(x)=2x+1
      \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{document}
```

My attempt is the folowing:

```
\newenvironment{sidebyside}[1]
{%
  \begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
  \csname align*\endcsname
}{%
  \csname endalign*\endcsname
  \end{minipage}
}
```

Which gives the error:

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line ... ended by \end{sidebyside}.
```

Comment: Use `\minipage` and `\endminipage`.

Comment: How would this work with the argument `#1`?

Comment: Just use it normally e.g. `\minipage{#1\linewidth}`, I think.

Comment: not the question, but in the first example, `0.5\linewidth` + `0.5\linewidth` + `0.5cm` is going to give you an overfull box .5cm too wide.  plus the paragraph indent, unless latex breaks it to two lines (which it may since you don't end the first minipage with a `%`; i didn't try).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a simpler syntax will help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newlength{\sbswidth}
\newenvironment{sidebysideeq}[1][0.5]
 {\[% start equation
  \setlength{\sbswidth}{#1\linewidth}%
  \minipage{\sbswidth}
  \centering
  $\!\aligned
 }
 {\endaligned$\endminipage\]}
\newcommand{\breaksideeq}{%
  \endaligned$\endminipage
  \setlength{\sbswidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\sbswidth}%
  \minipage{\sbswidth}
  \centering
  $\!\aligned
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{sidebysideeq}
  y_1(x)=x^2
\breaksideeq
  y_2(x)=2x+1
\end{sidebysideeq}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{sidebysideeq}[0.3]
  y_1(x)&=x^2\\
  y_2(x)&=x^3-x
\breaksideeq
  y_3(x)=2x+1+a+b+c+d+e+f+g
\end{sidebysideeq}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `sidebysideeq` tells the fraction of `\linewidth` reserved for the left part, default is 0.5.

[image]

One can easily add a key-value interface for setting more aspects of the environment: here I use a key for the left fraction and for the reciprocal vertical alignment. The default values are equivalent to `left=0.5` and `align=c`. The possible values for `align` are `c`, `t` or `b` (but the last one is probably not really useful).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,keyval}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\define@key{SBS}{left}{\def\SBS@left{#1}}
\define@key{SBS}{align}{\def\SBS@align{#1}}
\def\SBS@left{0.5}
\def\SBS@align{c}

\newlength{\sbswidth}
\newenvironment{sidebysideeq}[1][]
 {\[% start equation
  \setkeys{SBS}{#1}%
  \setlength{\sbswidth}{\SBS@left\linewidth}%
  \minipage[\SBS@align]{\sbswidth}
  \centering
  $\!\aligned[\SBS@align]
 }
 {\endaligned$\endminipage\]}
\newcommand{\breaksideeq}{%
  \endaligned$\endminipage
  \setlength{\sbswidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\sbswidth}%
  \minipage[\SBS@align]{\sbswidth}
  \centering
  $\!\aligned[\SBS@align]
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{sidebysideeq}
  y_1(x)=x^2
\breaksideeq
  y_2(x)=2x+1
\end{sidebysideeq}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{sidebysideeq}[left=0.3,align=t]
  y_1(x)&=x^2\\
  y_2(x)&=x^3-x
\breaksideeq
  y_3(x)=2x+1+a+b+c+d+e+f+g
\end{sidebysideeq}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to support `\tag`, then a more complex approach should be taken.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,keyval,environ}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\define@key{SBS}{left}{\def\SBS@left{#1}}
\define@key{SBS}{align}{\def\SBS@align{#1}}
\def\SBS@left{0.5}
\def\SBS@align{c}

\newlength{\sbswidth}
\NewEnviron{sidebysideeq}[1][]{%
  \par\centering
  \setkeys{SBS}{#1}%
  \penalty\predisplaypenalty
  \if\SBS@align t\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip\prevdepth\fi
  \setlength{\sbswidth}{\SBS@left\linewidth}%
  \expandafter\make@sidebysideeq\BODY\@nil
}

\def\make@sidebysideeq#1\breaksideeq#2\@nil{%
  \begin{minipage}[\SBS@align]{\sbswidth}
  \vskip-\baselineskip\vskip\abovedisplayskip
  \begin{align*}#1\end{align*}
  \vskip\belowdisplayskip
  \end{minipage}%
  \setlength{\sbswidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\sbswidth}%
  \begin{minipage}[\SBS@align]{\sbswidth}
  \vskip-\baselineskip\vskip\abovedisplayskip
  \begin{align*}#2\end{align*}
  \vskip\belowdisplayskip
  \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{sidebysideeq}[align=t]
  y_1(x)=x^2
\breaksideeq
  y_2(x)=2x+1
\end{sidebysideeq}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{sidebysideeq}[left=0.3,align=t]
  y_1(x)&=x^2 \tag{*}\\
  y_2(x)&=x^3-x
\breaksideeq
  y_3(x)=2x+1+a+b+c+d+e+f+g
\end{sidebysideeq}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this differs from Gonzalo Medina's solution? It looks to have more lines of code that achieve the same thing. I am not an expert at latex, thus I am here, but it looks like there is some automation going on in there. Could you elaborate for learning purposes?

Comment: @arynhard Not very different; but with this you use just *one* environment and specify the length only once. Besides, I use `aligned`, which is less expensive than `align*`.

Comment: I see it now, this is a more elegant solution. In fact I have been trying to figure out how I could achieve this. Having one environment is a lot cleaner. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Do you know how I might align each equation to the top of the environment. In some cases one side of `sidebysideeq` will have a lot more lines of math, and the other side gets vertically centered to it. Can I make this optional?

Comment: One comment, this breaks of I use `tag` in the environment. Which is important for me.

Comment: @arynhard Support for `\tag` added. The spacing should be OK, it's not really easy to get it right. ;-)

Comment: Has anyone noticed how there is a small indentation error in the first two examples? The first word, "Nulla" is indented a tiny bit! ...But not so in the last example! Why? I would love to use minipage inside equations, but this indentation error always bugs me, I would love to know how to stop it!

Answer (score 5):

`\begin{minipage}`, `\end{minipage}` won't work in the definition of the environment and will trigger an error

```
\begin{minipage} on input line 16 ended by \end{sidebyside}.
```

due to the way `align*` is processed (it reads the content more than once for calculating the alignments); when this internal processing finishes, the `\begin{minipage}` will incorrectly be matched to the `\end{sidebyside}` and the error occurs. If you use `equation` instead of `align`, then you can use `\begin{minipage}`, `\endminipage`, for example.

Here's one possibility, using `\minipage`, `\end{minipage}` instead:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{sidebyside}[1]
{%
  \minipage{#1\linewidth}
  \csname align*\endcsname
}{%
  \csname endalign*\endcsname
  \endminipage
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{sidebyside}{0.5}
  y_1(x)=x^2
\end{sidebyside}%
\begin{sidebyside}{0.5}
  y_2(x)=2x+1
\end{sidebyside}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Would you mind explaining why `\minipage` works but `\begin{minipage}` does not? Also, I am not too clear why the `csname` is necessary for `align`.

Comment: @Mico that's because I made some redundancy in the code. I'll fix it in some minutes.

Comment: @arynhard answer fixed!

Comment: @Mico answer fixed!

Comment: @arynhard `\csname` `\endcsname` is required since the name has the star `*`. It wouldn't be necessary for `align`, but it is required for `align*`.

Comment: @arynhard I added an explanation about `\minipage` vs `\begin{minipage}` to my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `environ` package and lead a simple life ;)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{sidebyside}[1]
{%
  \begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
  \begin{equation}
  \BODY
  \end{equation}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{sidebyside}{0.5}
  y_1(x)=x^2
\end{sidebyside}%
\begin{sidebyside}{0.5}
  y_2(x)=2x+1
\end{sidebyside}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can make the width option optional too.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{sidebyside}[1][0.5]
{%
  \begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
  \begin{equation}
  \BODY
  \end{equation}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{sidebyside}
  y_1(x)=x^2
\end{sidebyside}%
\begin{sidebyside}
  y_2(x)=2x+1
\end{sidebyside}

\end{document}
```

so that `\begin{sidebyside}` takes `0.5\linewidth` unless you specify it like `\begin{sidebyside}[0.4]`

Comment: You can replace `equation` environment with `align*` too here.