# Cannot wrap align and align*

Tags: environments, align

I am used to using `\newenvironment` to wrap an environment:

```
\newenvironment{wrappedequation}
    {Look out for the equation!
    \begin{equation}}
    {\end{equation}
    Phew, it's over.}
```

This works fine.  However, it doesn't seem to work with `align` or `align*`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newenvironment{wrappedalign}
    {Look out for the aligned equation!
    \begin{align}}
    {\undefinedcommand
    \end{align}
    Phew, it's over.}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrappedalign}\end{wrappedalign}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{align} on input line 9 ended by \end{wrappedalign}.
```

This error must be produced somehow very early in the expansion process (maybe in the argument-grabbing process?), because it doesn't mention the `\undefinedcommand` that I snuck in there.

EDIT:  Darn it, I knew that this looked familiar.  Is it the same as [some \newcommand instructions not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112558/some-newcommand-instructions-not-working) ?  Is there any (good) way to wrap `align` environments?

Comment: I believe the solution at [newenvironment: error with \begin{align} and \end{align}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236664) (use `\align` and `\endalign` instead of `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`, respectively) should work for your case too.

Comment: @PaulGessler, you are right!  Could you post that as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: No, better to mark as a duplicate. Then your question can help point future searchers to the already existing solution. :-)

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate, because it also asks for `align*` (without numbering). The solution given in the linked question does not apply for `align*`. Using `\align*` and `\endalign*` does not do the intended. After lots of digging, I found out ([from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223667/custom-environment-with-minipage-and-align)) that I could use `\csname align*\endcsname` and `\csname endalign*\endcsname` to achieve what I wanted. Also, it is important to have no space before `\endcsname`.